# error 404.Not found

Tags: c#, azure

Hi I am getting a "404 error.Not found" when I try to retrieve an image stored as a blob uri from my database table. The storage string is stored as follows: https://********.blob.core.windows.net/image/0d3f5611-b97e-411a-8979-7a20afb77ea6 To achieve this I have used the following code:

```
// Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("partsimageblob");
            var blobs = container.GetBlobReference(imagePart);
            var uri = blobs.Uri;
```

Comment: Please make sure your blob container's ACL is either `Container` or `Blob` and not `Private`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to post an answer to this question so it can be marked as such and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set blob container's ACL to either Container or Blob and not Private. This can be done in properties under the blob container.